# how to redirect domain name when changing servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, .htaccess

I have this problem. I've transferred bunch of websites to a new server, but some users still get to an old site/server and the reasons are:

1. DNS caching
2. Name servers/A records take time to switch to a new IP

Is there a way to somehow redirect all the people who still get to the old server? Is there a way to edit .htaccess file to point them to an IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could put this in the .htaccess on the root of the site:

```
Redirect permanent / http://newipordomain/
```